# Error during WebSocket handshake: Sec-WebSocket-Accept mismatch

Tags: c++, c, websocket

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Host: localhost:53000
Origin: null
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: hmiModel
Sec-WebSocket-Key: Hbw2xjBq6OTGXzxeuqrdVQ==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: x-webkit-deflate-frame
```

This is the request key i got from the client side on chrome browser.
After that i concatenated the key with the Magic String .

> Magic string is 258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11

Then i used SHA1 algorithm and i got the below hash values

> a5877edcaa04801d07c5687aad3a6cf03d26ad5c

Then i encode the above values using base64 and i got the encrypted value as

> Nzg1YWNkZTc0MGFhZDEwODVjNzA=

Then i send response handshake to the client

```
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Charset: ISO8859-1,UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive, Upgrade
WebSocket-Origin: localhost
WebSocket-Location: localhost
WebSocket-Protocol: hmiModel
Sec-webSocket-Version: 13
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: Nzg1YWNkZTc0MGFhZDEwODVjNzA=
```

but in console i got the error as "**Error during WebSocket handshake: Sec-WebSocket-Accept mismatch** "

so that onopen and onmessage event is not firing because of this error.

can Anyone tell me where i have done the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked the output of your calculation but your intermediate hash value looks suspiciously long.  Using the SHA1 code from [RFC4634](https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4634.txt), I use code like the following to calculate the handshake response

```
std::string key;
// populate key with content of Sec-WebSocket-Key header
key.append("258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11");
SHA1Context* sha1ctx = (SHA1Context*)malloc(sizeof(*sha1ctx));
(void)SHA1Reset(sha1ctx);
(void)SHA1Input(sha1ctx, key.c_str(), key.size());
uint8_t digest[SHA1HashSize];
(void)SHA1Result(sha1ctx, digest);
free(sha1ctx);
// convert std::string(&digest[0], sizeof(digest)) to base64
```

If you'd like more specific feedback, please edit your question to include your equivalent code.